# Breeze Mongo Angular autoGeneratedKey error

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, breeze

I'm using Breeze with Angular and MongoDB.

I included all the necessary services and scripts to make sure breeze works with angular and MongoDB.

However, when I try to save my changes I get the following error on the server:

```
ObjectIds and Guids are the only autoGenerated key types that Breeze currently supports, not: undefined
```

This error occurs in the mongoSaveHandler.js file of the mongobreeze module:

```
var keyDataType = entityType.keyDataType;
            if (keyDataType === "Guid") {
                e._id = createGuid();
            } else if (keyDataType == "MongoObjectId") {
                // instead of omitting the _id and having mongo update it, we want to set it ourselves so that we can do
                // fk fixup before going async
                e._id = new ObjectID();
            } else {
                that._raiseError(new Error("ObjectIds and Guids are the only autoGenerated key types that Breeze currently supports, not: " + keyDataType));
                return;
            }
```

I made sure that the id of my object is a mongo id:

```
function addVisit() {
    addType({
        name: 'Visit',
        dataProperties: {
            id: { type: DT.MongoObjectId },
            pain: { type: ID },
            paper: {type: ID},
            consistency: {type: ID}
        }
    });
}
```

But indeed when I log the entityType object it has no property keyDataType?

I can get everything to work if I just remove the error. Then my inserted objects look like this in MongoDB:

```
{ id: 5350d4e704a02e1f04000000,
pain: 50,
consistency: 50,
date: Fri Apr 18 2014 08:31:51 GMT+0100 (WEST),
_id: 5350d4e7101b04a9560e660a },
```

Meaning they have 2 ids?

When I try to query the database I get a nice response:

```
[
  {
    "id": "535052f504a02e79c6000000",
    "pain": 50,
    "consistency": 50,
    "_id": "535052f6f672174a4dffffd4"
  },
  {
    "id": "5350d1bb04a02e4e56000000",
    "pain": 50,
    "consistency": 50,
    "date": "2014-04-18T07:18:19.616Z",
    "_id": "5350d1bb101b04a9560e6606"
  },
  {
    "id": "5350d2c104a02e595c000000",
    "pain": 50,
    "consistency": 50,
    "date": "2014-04-18T07:22:41.696Z",
    "_id": "5350d2c1101b04a9560e6607"
  },
]
```

But somehow Breeze is unable to import this properly and I get a circular dependency.

[image]

Could this have something to do with the double ID's?

Comment: Attached image is OK. Every entity in breeze has entityAspect. EntityAspect in its turn has a back reference to its entity. Breeze works great with circular references. Look at EntityAspect docs http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html

Comment: Hmm I see but when I try to display them using angular I get an interpolate error due to the circular dependencies

Comment: Angular is not able to handle objects with circular references when it comes to bindings. You should make a projection from breeze entity to another javascript object without circular references for angular to work

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get DT.MongoObjectId from?  That isn't listed in the breeze docs as a supported data type so it is returning undefined as a type.  If you are properly generating the Id why not just use a string if it is immutable?

```
id : { type: DT.String }
```

Comment: it is patched by breeze.dataservice.mongo.js but it also doesn't work with Guid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a naming convention that would convert breeze's `"id"` field into mongo's `"_id"` and vice versa. It will eliminate double ID's
Here's the code for client side:

```
var convention = new breeze.NamingConvention({
    serverPropertyNameToClient: function (serverPropertyName) {
        switch (serverPropertyName) {
            case '_id':
                return 'id';
            default :
                return serverPropertyName;
        }
    },
    clientPropertyNameToServer: function (clientPropertyName) {
        switch (clientPropertyName) {
            case 'id':
                return '_id';
            default:
                return clientPropertyName;
        }
    }
});

convention.setAsDefault();
```